# I loose all my data when i change the orientation of my phone, or when navigte between tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I have a tabHost in a TabActivity, it contains 3 Tabs, and each one of theese tab has it's own class, i can navigate between the different Tabs using an Intent, Once i change the orientation of my phone, or when i change the current tab to another, i lost all the data(ImageView, text on my editTexts) in the previous Tab.

**Updated:**

I tried the onSavedInstanceState method, but nothing changed:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vendre);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SelectedImage);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {

        imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("image"));
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.VendreName)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("nomProduit"));
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.VendreDescription)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("description"));
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.VendrePrix)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("prix"));
    }
}


    @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("nomProduit", ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.VendreName)).getText().toString());
    outState.putString("description", ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.VendreDescription)).getText().toString());
    outState.putString("prix", ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.VendrePrix)).getText().toString());
    Bitmap b= ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    outState.putParcelable("image",b);
}
```

It seems that this method is never called.

Comment: And what do you want? Also please past some code.

Comment: when orientation changes activity is destroyed and recreated. override onSavedInstanceState() and onRestoredInstanceState() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: This is what i'm looking for, if it's possible please type the code in a separate answer, so i can set your answer as accepted.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  line in AndroidManifest.xml for your activity. It is not a good solution.

Comment: yeah i don't want to loose the ability of changing the orientation of my screen.

Comment: you can change orientation

Comment: okey then, but can you tell me what makes this solution 'not a good solution' as you said.

Comment: Managing orientation change programatically is the best way. My answer is just an easy solution. Try with that...if it is not working let me know.